# How to calculate derivatives of power functions?

Tags: derivatives

How can I calculate the derivative of the.following function any help is appreciated.

$$10^{x^3 +x^2\arctan x}$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: The chain rule is the way to go. Put $f(u) = 10^u$, $u = x^3+x^2\cdot \arctan x$, thus $f'(x) = f'(u)\cdot u'(x)= ....$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: We know that the derivative of $a^x$ is $a^x\log a$. Generalising this, we get, $$a^{f(x)} = a^{f(x)}(\log_{e} a) \frac{d}{dx}f(x)$$ In our problem, $a=10, f(x) = x^3 + x^2\arctan x$. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it log(a) or log of the whole thing that is log(ad/dx(fx))

Comment: And log base what ? Thank u